# checkSeflPermission always return '0' whether permission is in enable/disable

Tags: android, android-permissions

i am using below code to check whether the camera permission is in enabled state or disabled state.

whatever state, it always returning '0'. don't know why?

code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean isPermissionEnabled(String permissionToCheck){
    if (mActivity.checkSelfPermission(permissionToCheck) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have declared permission in `manifest`

Answer (score 1):

Second if condition is return true or false for enable/disable permission:

```
       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to camera - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Target method properly along with, add `permission` to `manifest.xml` and make sure your `mActivity` is not null (use `this` instead, my preference):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean isPermissionEnabled(String permissionToCheck) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
        (this, permissionToCheck) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because i used `getContext()` to get context, But once i changed it to `getActivity()`, It all get fixed!!

Sample working code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}
```

Note: I was doing this all inside a fragment, So you might have to use `MainActivity.this` equivalent, Hopefully it will work :D